# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a tuple in my table. The data is from a form or received.
My database:
[image]

**View**

```
@extends('plantilla')
@section('contenido')
<div class="formulario">
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'servicio/create', 'files' => true))}}

    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="direccion" name="dirrecion" placeholder="Dirección" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="cliente" name="cliente" placeholder="Nombre Cliente" >
    <input type="time" name='horainicio' id='horainicio' min='time' max='time' >
    {{Form::file('pdf', array('title' => 'Search for a file to add'))}}
    {{Form::select('idtecnico', $tecnico_selector)}}
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary ')) }} 
{{Form::close()}}
    </div>  
    @stop
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('servicio/create', function(){
$tecnicos = Tecnico::all();
    $tecnico_selector = array();
    foreach ($tecnicos as $tecnico) {
        $tecnico_selector[$tecnico->idTecnico] = $tecnico->Nombre;
    }
    return View::make('formservicio', array('tecnico_selector' => $tecnico_selector));
 });
 Route::post('servicio/create', array('uses' => 'ServicioController@doCreate'));
```

**Model**

```
class Servicio extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Servicio';
protected $primaryKey = 'idServicio';
protected $fillable = array(
                            'Direccion',
                            'RutaPDF',
                            'Completado'
                            );
public function materialUsado(){
    return $this->hasMany('Material_Usado', 'idMaterial_Usado');
}

public function tecnicos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio', 'Tecnico_idTecnico');
}
    }
```

**Controller**

```
class ServicioController extends BaseController{
public function doCreate(){
    $rules = array(
                'idtecnico' => 'required',
                'direccion' => 'required',
                'cliente' => 'required'
                );
    $validator = Validator:: make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('servicio/create')
                ->withErros($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }else{
        $input = array(
                'Direccion' => Input::get('direccion'),
                'Cliente' => Input::get('cliente'),
                'Completado' => '0'
                );

        Servicio::create($input);
        /*$servicio = new Servicio;
        $servicio->Direccion = Input::get('direccion');
        $servicio->Cliente = Input::get('cliente');
        $servicio->Completado = '0';
        $servicio->tecnicos->attach($idtecnico);
        $servicio->save();*/

        $path = public_path().'/servicio/'.$servicio->idServicio;
        File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true); // creamos la carpeta
        $archivoPdf = Input::file('pdf');
        $archivoPdf->move($path, 'servicio');

        /*$servicio->RutaPDF = $path.'/servicio';
        $servicio->save();*/







    }
}
}
```

When completely changes the form and send it, the following error

[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: Like the error message states, you have a `Closure` (an anonymous function) somewhere in `$this->attributes`. Functions cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo in your controller: `->withErros($validator)` - it should be `withErrors`. The difference is big.

Laravel converts `withErros($validator)` into `with(['erros' => $validator])`, which means trying to put the entire validator object into the session. To put things into the session storage, it needs to be serialized first, which is what is causing the error.

Comment: thank you. This was of great help --- changing from `->with_errors` and `->with_input` to `->withErrors` and `->withInput` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem:

The problem was:

- I was validating an input does not exist.
- The name of the column(database) is not similar to the name of the input
- The column(database) is not null