# Laravel "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Tags: php, laravel

When I go to store a dataset in Laravel, I sometimes get this error and haven't found a solution to it.

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
Open: ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php
     */
    public function save()
    {
        $this->addBagDataToSession();

        $this->ageFlashData();

        $this->handler->write($this->getId(), serialize($this->attributes));

        $this->started = false;
```

Here is the function being called when the error occurs:

```
public function store()
    {

        $data = Input::all();
        $validator = array('first_name' =>'required', 'last_name' => 'required', 'email' => 'email|required_without:phone', 'phone' => 'numeric|size:10|required_without:email', 'address' => 'required');
        $validate = Validator::make($data, $validator);
        if($validate->fails()){
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', $validate);
        } else {
            $customer = new Customer;
            foreach (Input::all() as $field => $value) {
                if($field == '_token') continue;
                $customer->$field = $value;
            }
            $customer->save();
            return View::make('admin/customers/show')->withcustomer($customer);
        }
    }
```

What is causing this serialization error?

Answer (score 9):

Just replace following line:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message', $validate);
```

with this:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate);
```

Also, you may use something like this (To repopulate the form with old values):

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
```

In the `view` you can use `$errors` variable to get the error messages, so if you use `$errors->all()` then you'll get an array of error messages and to get a specific error you may try something like this:

```
{{ $errors->first('email') }} // Print (echo) the first error message for email field
```

Also, in the following line:

```
return View::make('admin/customers/show')->withcustomer($customer);
```

You need to change the dynamic method to `withCustomer` not `withcustomer`, so you'll be able to access `$customer` variable in your `view`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message', $validate);
```

You are telling Laravel to serialize the entire validator object into session.  To redirect with errors, use the `withErrors` method:

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate);
```

This will take the error messages out of the validator and flash those to session prior to redirecting.  The way you're doing it now you're trying to store the entire class in Session which is causing your error.

Another issue I see is that I don't think there's a `withcustomer` method on the `View` class:

```
return View::make('admin/customers/show')->withcustomer($customer);
```

Try changing that to either just `with`:

```
return View::make('admin/customers/show')->with('customer', $customer);
```

or make sure to capitalize the `Customer` portion:

```
return View::make('admin/customers/show')->withCustomer($customer);
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23451535/697370).

Comment: Actually `return View::make('admin/customers/show')->with($customer);` won't work and `OP` has used `withcustomer` but it should be `withCustomer`, so `$customer` variable will be available in the `view`, it's `dynamic method`.

Comment: Good to know. I fixed the couple of minor issues I missed.  I haven't seen that usage of `with` before so I was a little lost.