# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Error: "Serialization of Closure is not allowed" while storing the data.

I am using CKEditor on textarea. Data is stored when there is not more text but when there is more text like the first question and it's answered on https://www.lipsum.com  then it shows error while saving the data.

Store Function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'noticeTitle'        => 'required',
        'noticeDesc'       => 'required',
    ]);

    $notice = new Notice;
    $notice->noticeTitle = $request->input('noticeTitle');
    $notice->noticeDesc = $request->input('noticeDesc');

    $notice->batch_id = $request->input('targetedGroup');


    if($request->hasFile('add_file')) {
        $noticeTitle = $request->input('noticeTitle');

        $filename  = $request->add_file->getClientOriginalName();

        $request->add_file->storeAs('public/noticeFile/additionalFiles', $noticeTitle.'_'.$filename);
        $path = $noticeTitle.'_'.$filename;

        $notice->file = $path;
    }
    dd($notice);
    try{
        $notice->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'Notice Saved');
        return redirect()->route('notice.index');
    }
    catch (\Throwable $th){
        Session::flash('danger', $th);
        return redirect()->route('notice.index');
    }
}
```

dump of $notice variable goes as

```
"noticeTitle" => "Lorem Ipsum Notice New"
    "noticeDesc" => """
      <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
      
      <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text  ▶
      """
    "batch_id" => "3"
    "file" => "Lorem Ipsum Notice New_s.pdf"
  ]
```

Comment: I don't know where it's happening but that dump shows a serialized model. Add a dd before file handling logic to see if its serialized there as well?

Comment: `"noticeTitle" => "Lorem Ipsum Noticefaafs"
    "noticeDesc" => """
      <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
      
      <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text  ▶
      """
    "batch_id" => "3"
  ]`

Comment: I think its same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem wasn't within the store function it's on migration. For data on CKEditor, I was using a `string` on migration. Changed it to `text` then problem solved.

All thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003432/10590832
I got an idea.

Cheers,